# How to setup hibernate.cfg.xml via Java code?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, configuration, runtime

Well, I'm working on an application which syncs two databases.
I need to setup hibernate.cfg.xml for 2 databases. Postgresql and Firebird.
I'd like to create a generic class to set up my hibernate.cfg.xml.

I'd like to do something like this:

```
currentSessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration()
.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", entity.getDialect())
.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", entity.getDriverClass())
```

I need a new hibernate.cfg.xml for the second database but I can't set up it via xml, I need to do it through Java code.

How should I do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Hibernate Configuration](http://vladmihalcea.com/the-minimal-configuration-for-testing-hibernate/) class to replace the hibernate.cfg.xml alltogether:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Entity1.class);
ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry
            = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();            
sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
```

The [Configuration](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html) class allows you to:

- add classes
- add properties

Here you have [an example on GitHub](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-master-class/blob/master/core/src/test/java/com/vladmihalcea/hibernate/masterclass/laboratory/util/AbstractTest.java).

Comment: Well, this setup is for the HibernateUtil class, I want to build a class to setup the hibernate xml file, without using xml.

Comment: Then you can use the Configuration class to replace the whole hibernate.cfg.xml. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you :D you did a nice job \o/